# Websocket onclose event - Client Side

Tags: javascript, event-handling, websocket, client-side, webrtc

I'm trying to see what the restrictions for a client with an open [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) connection to server are.

Specifically the scenarios where a user closes the tab or navigates to another page are interesting to me. I'm not really sure how to test that situation, since the console is gone in those scenarios.

I'm curious about this is because I'm working with WebRTC peer-connections. I'am seeing unexpected behaviour when two clients are connected via a peer-connection and then one of the peers closes their tab.

For whatever reason *the peer that did not leave never gets the disconnect event from the leaving peer*.